# What is a segment in NCAR Command Language(NCL)

Tags: command, segment, ncl

What is a 'segment' used for in NCL (we can create a segment and it contains names of the data but i don t know it's utility)
After years of experience using Java and Php programming. I started using NCL, and I am faced with lack of documentation and of the help of the community.
So, what 'segment' mean in NCL programming Language.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I found: A segment is a space allocated in the memory that can be used as an object. So, when we create the segment using the NCL we define the variables and the attributes that this segment has to contain, then this 'object' will be filled with data and used whenever needed, after usage you need to delete the segment or liberate the memory it is using